# clonezilla backup partition to disk

Tags: clone, clonezilla

I want to back up only 1 partition of my 1TB to another new external hard drive(1TB).

1TB has 440GB of ubuntu operating system. So I want to clone only that. Not entire disk. Clone 440GB to 1TB WD Drive

How do I do that?

Comment: Clonezilla has options for full drive or just a partition cloning. It's just a matter of selecting what you want to do in its intuitive wizard. But the exact operation you want will fail to boot because it misses the bootloader.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks this totally makes sense. But if we use bootloader like refind. Can this solution work?

Comment: Yes, probably. I never used it though. Also in alive session, after mounting the relevant partitions, and running the os-prober / reinstalling Grub should work as well. But if it's a UEFI system it's much easier to clone the ESP along with the Ubuntu partition.